# Rails: Optimize query N+1 with same table one_to_many and scope conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, select-n-plus-1

Here's a challenge I'm facing, using Rails 5 (I use [Skylight](https://www.skylight.io) service that reports N+1 queries, and their recommended solution is [here](https://www.skylight.io/support/performance-tips#repeated-queries), but it's not enough in my case).

I have a table `nodes` and a single `Node` can have several `nodes` related to it (there's a column called `parent_node_id`) that gives me the ability to relate **one to many**.

```
class Node < ApplicationRecord
  ...
  belongs_to :parent_node, foreign_key: :parent_node_id, class_name: 'Node', optional: true, inverse_of: :nodes
  has_many :nodes, foreign_key: :parent_node_id, class_name: 'Node'
  ...
end
```

**Important**
The level of hierarchy is maximum 1. That means that a `node.nodes.first.node`
 does not happen. A `node` that has a `parent_node` does not have any more `nodes`.

Issue is that I'm facing performance issues with N+1 because it's not enough to include the `nodes` in the original query, because inside the loop I query each record with a different scope. Here's a sample code that exposes the issue:

```
# In a controller, including nodes so it does not query inside
nds = Node.some_scope.include(:nodes)
nds.each do |nd|
  ...
  # In a model
  # If I loop inside, there's no extra SQL queries, all good
  nd.nodes.each do |nd2|
    ...
  end
  ...
  # In a model
  # Here's the N+1 issue
  nd.nodes.another_scope.each do |nd3|
    ...
  end
  # Returns a value to the controller
  ...
end
```

That will anyway triggers the SQL queries for each `nd3` variable since there's `another_scope` that modifies the original `nds` values, and I can not include the condition in the `nds` values because the `nodes` that don't meet the criteria in `another_scope` are needed for `nd2`.

Is there a way to optimize this?

Comment: you can add another association `has_many :whatever_nodes, -> { another_scope's conditions written here}, foreign_key: :parent_node_id, class_name: 'Node'` now you can do this `nds = Node.some_scope.include(:nodes, :whatever_nodes)`.

Comment: I think that @DennisKrupelnik suggested a suitable answer. Just for clarification, you should use `#includes` method instead of `#include` for query batching

Comment: @helperhelperov Yes he did. I'm just pointing out that it can be improved. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `another_scope` with `select { |n| n.satisfies_another_scope_criteria? }`

Since you've already fetched all children, there's no need to filter them in the database once again unless there's a `limit` clause in `another_scope`

Comment: You're right!, although if anyway I'm iterating through all of them again (in the `each` section), wouldn't it be better to just `next unless criteria` as first line in the loop?

Comment: You have to benchmark it. With CRuby, I'd go with `select`.